# Dynamic Xamarin Image Source Binding

Tags: variables, xamarin, binding

I have the same question please..

I have the url this way:

**mydomain.com/gallery/COMPANY_GUID/items/ITEM_GUID/600x400.png**

where COMPANY_GUID and ITEM_GUID comes from the database here:

```
public class ItemDetails
{
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int item_guid { get; set; }
    public int merchant_guid { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string item_description { get; set; }
    public string item_price { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set the Images source **{Binding item_image}** where the item_image should be a dynamic variable comes from the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ItemDetails
{
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int item_guid { get; set; }
    public int merchant_guid { get; set; }
    public string item_name { get; set; }
    public string item_description { get; set; }
    public string item_price { get; set; }
    //Add this field like this.
    public string item_image {
        get {
                return string.Format("mydomain.com/gallery/{0}/items/{1}/600x400.png", merchant_guid, item_guid);
            }
        }
    }
```

Try to add one field `item_image` as given in the above code. This will return what you need, dynamically. Hope this will help you.

Comment: or simply write a converter

Comment: Glad to see it helped!!